# How to set vertical margins for beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, margins

My talk slides use a mostly-white background image (supplied by organizers) that has some visual patterns at the bottom. I would like to tell `beamer` to not cover these patterns (as it makes text less readable).

I can set horizontal margins with `\setbeamersize`.

But how can I set *vertical* margins for all my slides?

Comment: @Papiro: I need to set *vertical* margins.

Comment: Beamer moves the text area down so it won't overlap with the title bar, but `\textheight` is not resized. This can be seen by putting `\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{example-image}` in a normal and `plain` frame.
It seems the only solution to your problem is not to put anything at the bottom of the frame.

Answer (score 16):

For the top margin you may try to place a `\vspace` in the frametitle:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \vspace{2cm}\\
    \insertframetitle
}
```

and for the bottom margin, a `\vspace` in the footline:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \vspace{0.5cm}
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: A MWE would be useful. However, `beamer` loads the `geometry` package, so you can play around with the following and set the best result for you (it accepts negative values): `\geometry{
  paperwidth=\the\paperwidth,
  paperheight=\the\paperheight,
  hmargin=1cm,%
  vmargin=0cm,%
  head=0.5cm, %
  headsep=0pt,%
  foot=0.5cm %
}`

Comment: I didn't mentioned that but my solution can't work with a `[plain]` frame because there isn't any frame title nor footline in this kind of frame. Aren't you in this case?

Comment: Your `footline` solution worked perfectly for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Putting vertical space before the frame title does not solve the problem for the frames without a title.

You could instead try increasing the `\headsep`:

```
\addtolength{\headsep}{0.6cm}
```

Comment: In my case this breaks the frames with a title by shifting the titlebar downwards, which is unwanted.