# Customized template for beamer

Tags: beamer, templates, pgf-core

I'm a convinced `beamer` user, but in my institute they ask me to follow some template (of course prepared with PowerPoint). I would like to mimic it as much as possible with `beamer`, because otherwise I'm afraid I will have to use PowerPoint. However, I think that setting up `beamer` would require extensive knowledge of how `beamer` and `pgf` work internally, which is something I unfortunately lack right now.

I attach a couple of snapshots of the title and the regular slides with the hope that some expert can give some advice on how to proceed. The image in the top and the logo are images I have, of course. The problem are the blue squares and the lack of sectioning …

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just another approach:

Take the PowerPoint-pages and save them as pdf. Then you can use the pdf-pages as background in your beamer-presentation.

Then you define the available area for your texts (position of title and text area).

Don't forget to use the correct fonts.

The background can be changed with:

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{my_pdf_copy_of_empty_ppt_template}
}
```

---

A more complete example with some additional commands to move the title and footer block.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
%Add background image
\usebackgroundtemplate{
   \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{my_pdf_copy_of_empty_ppt_template}
}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vspace{2cm}}%Shift the title block
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\vspace{2cm}}%Shift the foot block
\setbeamersize{%shift the horizontal borders.
  text margin right=5cm,
  text margin left=5cm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}{Sub-title}
\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, I like this pragmatic solution. I had the hope of learning a bit more about pgf, though. I will not mark it as "the" answer for the moment, to see if someone offers a "more beamer-like" approach.

Comment: @knut: could you please detail a bit more on "define the available area for your texts (position of title and text area)" (e.g. with one or two examples)

Comment: As a quick response some questions with the same prupose: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57444/can-i-add-border-margin-into-beamer-frame-body, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109815/how-to-set-vertical-margins-for-beamer-frame,

Comment: @ebo I just added an example. I think it is difficult to build an example for all variants, If you have a more complex template, maybe you can create a question "How to define the text block in a specific area in beamer?" (including a little picture to show the result you need),

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I was asking for: the key macros/variables and their basic use, in order to further investiguate!